# English equivalent for French “Culture générale"?

Tags: translation, culture, french

The French expression *“[Culture générale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale)"* is deeply entrenched in philosophical and humanist ideas:

> Le projet d’une culture générale est intrinsèquement lié à des
>   réflexions à propos de l'humanité, qu'elle soit conçue comme nature
>   humaine ou encore comme dépassement de la nature par la culture (ou
>   « seconde nature »). Durant la Renaissance, elle forme l'idéal de
>   l'« honnête homme ». La problématique de la culture générale est au
>   cœur de ce que l'on a pu appeler la « crise de l'éducation » (La crise
>   de la culture de Hannah Arendt).

Wikipedia translates the expression into *General knowledge*, but *General knowledge* sounds much wider than *Culture générale*. Is there any better translation?

Answer (score 2):

It is always very difficult to translate core philosophical terms like this. They often have long histories behind them, which cannot be bracketed out (think of Plato's *logos*); and translations in one generation have a tendency of becoming fixed, so that they are added to the history in the target language (think of *transcendence*, the traditional English translation of Hegel's *Aufhebung*).

In this case, however, the solution happens to be clear: Arendt wrote this in English, not French, so you need only consult the original text, *Between Past and Future*. The French edition, according to Wikipedia, is based on the 2nd edition, 1968.